# Explain Analyze Explained in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

If I'm running  the following query on PostgreSQL:

```
select *
from osm_pois_v06 pp
where pp.geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(8.174,48.298,12.431,50.930,4326);
```

I have to wait `1,34` minutes.

But if I'm doing an execution plan (explain analyze) with the mentioned query, then I have the following output:

[image]

The plan tells me that the  execution time is `2,624` seconds. But why is it less than 1,34 minutes?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using pgAdmin to fetch a result set of over 600000 rows.

pgAdmin is known to be slow when displaying large result sets. You'd be better off with `psql`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to estimate the impact of slow client software and/or network connection on you query execution is to add 'create temp table as ' before your select. If that runs in 4 seconds, and 1:34 without the 'create temp' part, it is a safe bet that the bottleneck is in transferring the result set out of the DB and processing it on the receiving end.

Comment: `explain (analyze)` does **not** give an estimate. It reports the **real** execution time on the server without any data transfer to the client

Comment: Oh - sorry - didn't know, is that a Postgres specific thing?. I've removed the last comment about the estimate and left the first part about the create temp, which is useful on most (if not all) db-platforms

Comment: Well, creating the temp table adds additional overhead to the runtime (because the data needs to be written). And it is not necessary because `explain (analyze)` will give you a more accurate information on how long the _retrieval_ of the data takes

Comment: In 100% Postgres context you are right I'm sure. All the rest of us have to trade one overhead for another (much) smaller one and take a wild guess from there...

Comment: Well, the question **is** about Postgres. And other DBMS offer similar features (e.g. Oracle with the `set autotrace` option)